# Serializing a collection in JSON.NET not working

Tags: c#, class, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to make a collection of WebPages' URLs and their names using classes in C#. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize them into a JSON string.

Here's my WebPage object class

```
class WebPage
{
    private string Name;
    private string URL;

    public WebPage(string name, string uRL)
    {
        Name = name;
        URL = uRL;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public string GetURL()
    {
        return URL;
    }
}
```

I'm using a `List<WebPage>` called `pageCollection` that I'm adding all the WebPages to, but when I run the code like so:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pageCollection);
```

The string output is just empty brackets. What's the problem here?

Comment: You need to have a default constructor in your class and public properties in the class for this to work.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya whoops yes this does seem to be the problem. Thanks

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya can you point out to the documentation that mentions this ?

Answer (score -1):

Ok so as the comments said quite quickly, my problem was that my properties were private. Set them to public and removed the getters/setters and it was solved

Comment: No, the code has no properties at all, just private fields. Also `GetName()` is not a "getter"

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you create a proper POCO that encompasses just your properties. Then ensure they're made public. In a separate class, you'll want to include a constructor as well. The code as you have it will not work.